# How do I scrape the website link on the page?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've tried using {"a", {"target":"_blank"}) to grab the web address in this listing, but this doesn't work.

What is the right way to scrape the link in this situation?  Should I be using {"target":"*something*"} or {"href":"*something*"}?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.gym-directory.com/listing/bulldog-gym/"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print soup.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_TITLE"}).text 
print soup.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_map_location"}).text 
print soup.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_phoneNum"}).text
print soup.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_EMAIL"}).text
print soup.find("a",{"target":"_blank"}).text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `href`:

```
soup.find("a", {"target":"_blank"})["href"]
```